# How can I programmatically generate a PDF and save it on S3 using Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, pdfkit

I am trying to generate a PDF using PDFKit

```
html = '<b>test</b>'
kit = PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')
pdf = kit.to_pdf
```

this works fine, and I can save the data to disk if I want to.

I have a simple model :

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader, mount_on: :filename
end
```

when I do :

```
a = Attachment.new
a.file = pdf
```

I receive the following error :

```
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
```

I prefer not to have to save the PDF to disk before uploading because I'll be using Heroku.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out? hitting same error right now

Comment: I ended up doing https://gist.github.com/limratana/0b2401a0e8bed86dc1e which worked.

Answer (score 1):

As the gist by William is not working for me, here is what I did to resolve the problem:

```
html = '<html><head></head><body>foo!</body></html>'
file = PDFKit.new html
file.to_pdf.gsub(/\0/, '')
```

The idea comes from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910040/exec-string-contains-null-byte-argumenterror). Side effects may apply.

Comment: While cleaning out my gists a few months ago I had deleted it forgetting that I had referenced it here. Thanks for putting a solution here.