# How to map data imported via xlsx with no headers in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import, xlsx, roo

I want to add an import function for the users of my rails app, however the files that they will import won't have a header and the interesting data will start at row 8. In the rows I only need 2 fields
Here is an example of a line in the xlsx file :

```
751,"01/17/2015","11:17:32","60","TDFSRDSK","2","10","-1","0","3","","26","3","","","1","0"
```

I'll only need the date and the number in 4th field (60) and add them to an SQL table
I have a problem with the mapping and how to do it. I've tried to do it based on the railscast tutorial and roo doc but I can't manage to make it work.

```
def self.import(file)
 xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(file)
 xlsx.each_row do |row|
  date = row[2]
  value = row[4]
  user_id = current_user.id
  product.create(:date => date, :valeur => value, :user_id => user_id)
 end
end
```

And the error I get :

```
no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String
```

I'm really new to rails/ruby so I'm not even sure the mapping code is supposed to be like that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to read the contents of the uploaded file into a String object first:

```
xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(file.read)
```

You can refer to [the relevant Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) for details on how this works.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I do this I get the following error "string contains null byte", when I look on google many answers says it about a bug with rails 4.0.2 but I don't think it must be the case, any idea where this comes from?

Comment: @dogg You probably have null bytes (zeros) in your input file. You should remove them (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910040/exec-string-contains-null-byte-argumenterror).